# How do I copy a Function to select columns in an entire spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an inventory report and the rows go by item and the columns go like this:
Inventory - Stock Shipped Out - Inventory - Stock Shipped Out ect.

I want each items Inventory figure to be the sum of the two cells to the left. i.e. The Inventory of the week before minus the inventory that was shipped out.Thus showing the stock we currently have.  I want to apply this to the entire years report.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `inventory` is in column A & `stock shipped out` is on column B, the formula for `current inventory` in column C would be:

```
=A2-B2
```

You can apply this throughout your spreadsheet by hovering over the bottom right-hand-side of the cell in column C until you see the crosshair appear, then simply drag the the formula down over the cells you wish to apply it (or double click to automatically apply it all the way down your spreadsheet alongside populated columns to the left-hand-side of it).